# React Native using Navigator.BreadcrumbNavigationBar showing warning on unique key prop

Tags: react-native

I'm using a very simple example of Navigator + Navigator.BreadcrumbNavigationBar, following very closely to this example from UIExplorer project https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b39b97546ac0e493723d73149c6950b04c2f203c/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/BreadcrumbNavSample.js

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of NavigatorBreadcrumbNavigationBar. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

I've tried stripping everything the Navigator needs and as soon as I add `<Navigator.BreadcrumbNavigationBar>` tag I see the warning on console. Any ideas?

Comment: may be add unique property "key"?

Comment: To what component? Which component in the Navigator / Navigator.BreadcrumbNavigationBar has multiple child?

Comment: That's easy. Seems one of the descendants
 NavigatorBreadcrumbNavigationBar. You can explore them with a good React Developer Tool  https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html